# Excel auto sort with index is not giving the right order

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi,

I want Excel to automatically sort my rows according to their rank so I used the INDEX function. My source data looks like this:

```
      N     O
```

[image: .]

I entered this formula on B2 and then dragged it all the way down: 
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N2)

However my destiny cells look like this

```
 A    B
```

[image]

Please notice the order for the first 4 elements is right but from hereafter it goes all wrong. Why is that? I looked and looked at the formulas on the destiny cells and everything seems to be alright

```
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N2)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N3)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N4)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N5)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N6)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N7)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N8)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N9)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N10)
=INDEX($O$2:$O$11,N11)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1484309/edit) to include the content of the cells. It is very hard to make out what's actually happening at the moment. Use mock data if the real data is confidential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is what I *think* you want, try:

```
=INDEX(O$1:O$11,MATCH(ROW()-1,N$2:N$11,0))
```

Comment: It worked by changing +1 to -1. Thank you. Although I would appreciate an explanation on why didnt the formula I tried first work.

Comment: You need to find the row with the correct rank (using `Match`) before you use `Index` to get its content.

Comment: I see. Thank you. By the way, is there any way to reflect not only the value of the cell but also the font color?

Comment: You would need VBA for that

Comment: Yep, I kinda read about it. Thats a shame. Thanks anyway.